# Cannot Configure CLion for Linking C++

Tags: c++, macos, linker, clion

I have a simple c++ example that I am trying to compile on a MacOSX machine using the CLion IDE.  The goal is to use header files and cmake to compile this code on CLion with an aim to expand to something bigger and so for now, I have simplified my code to have a bar.h header file and a bar.cpp implementation file. I am getting compilation issues during linking. My code looks as follows:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "bar.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    cout<<"starting"<<endl;
    Bar bar = Bar("Using Bar Function From Main");
    bar.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project(librarytest)

add_executable(myprog main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(bars)

target_link_libraries(myprog PRIVATE bars)
```

**bars\bar.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class Bar{
private:
    std::string s;
public:
    Bar(std::string s);
    void foo();
};
```

**bars\bar.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class Bar{
private:
    std::string s;
public:
    Bar(std::string s){
        std::cout<<"Function Bar"<<std::endl;
        this->s = s;
    }
    void foo(){
        std::cout << this->s << std::endl;
    }
};
```

**bars\CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(bars OBJECT
        bar.cpp
)
target_include_directories(bars PUBLIC .)
```

I get the following error message from my CLion CMake build (I have obfuscated by personal details/directory):

```
====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /{obfuscated-for-security}/testingincludes/cmake-build-debug --target all
[3/3] Linking CXX executable myprog
FAILED: myprog 
: && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -g -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  bars/CMakeFiles/bars.dir/bar.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myprog.dir/main.cpp.o -o myprog   && :
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Bar::foo()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "Bar::Bar(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have searched other Stack Overflow articles on similar errors but none can explain the issue as it pertains to linking on the OSX.  I have followed some of the guidance like re-installing the compiler.

Can anyone suggest how to get this working on the MacOSX using CLion?  Any pointers or suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: You already define the class `Bar` in the header file. By also defining it in the source file you break the one-definition rule. Only define (implement) the *functions* in the source file.

Comment: Your program is failing to compile because you violated the one definition rule. You have two definitions of `Bar`, and your compiler just so happens to be choosing the one that doesn't have inline member function definitions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the build (AFAIK), it's the code.

Your bar.cpp file should look like this

```
#include "bar.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Bar::Bar(std::string s){
    std::cout<<"Function Bar"<<std::endl;
    this->s = s;
}

void Bar::foo(){
    std::cout << this->s << std::endl;
}
```

Your version duplicates the `Bar` class definition in both the header and cpp file. My version includes the `Bar` class definition and just adds the definitions of the constructor and member function.

Comment: I have tried that before.  I get the following error message:

/{Obfuscated}/testingincludes/bars/bar.cpp
/{Obfuscated}/testingincludes/bars/bar.cpp:4:7: error: redefinition of 'Bar'
class Bar{
      ^
/Users/shenoyd/Documents/workspace/delme/testingincludes/bars/./bar.h:4:7: note: previous definition is here
class Bar{
      ^
1 error generated.

Comment: It's worth emphasizing the the problem isn't that their are _duplicate_ definitions of `Bar` (which is fine between translation units), but that their are _different_ definitions of `Bar` (ODR violation). Their compiler is presumably seeing the definition in `Bar.h` first and subsequently ignoring all other definitions, hence why it never notices the version with inline member function definitions and emits a diagnostic about undefined symbols.

Comment: @dshenoy My code does not generate that error message. Look carefully at my code, it's not the same as the code you are compiling.

Comment: @dshenoy It's clear from your error message that both your files have the text `class Bar {` in them, that's not true of my code.

Comment: @Brian I think the OPs misunderstanding is more fundamental than violations of the ODR. They don't know how to write an out of line member function definition.

Comment: @john Agreed - I am just offering some explanation for why the error they're getting is about undefined symbols